# Search Engine using Solr

Tags: xml, solr, indexing

I want to extract the Infobox data from the wikipedia dump and index it using Solr.

Out of the wikipedia dump I have extracted 5000 xml files to work upon. Should I extract the infobox data from these xml files in a separate xml or let it be in the same xml ?

How to enter the data in solr schema as no tags are present in infobox.xml that I have exracted.

```
Infobox musical artist <!-- See Wikipedia:WikiProject_Musicians -->
| name                = Russ Conway
| image                 =
| caption            = Russ Conway, pictured on the front of his 1959 [[Extended play|EP]] ''More Party Pops''.
| image_size            = 
| background          = non_vocal_instrumentalist
| birth_name          = Trevor Herbert Stanford
| alias               = 
| birth_date          = birth date|1925|09|2|df=y
```